# Should I add the information in both side

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to unity ,plz forgive me asking these questions 
It bumps out : default reference will only be applied in edit mode
Is it important, what is that?
Should I need to add the information(food and border ) to both sides?

[image: nextimage]

[image: ou]

Comment: wait, what??? if you apply the script to your camera, then assign the FoodPrefab and Transforms to the camera's `SpawnFood` it will be with the camera throughout the game. if you assign the FoodPrefab and Transforms to the `SpawnFood` Script then when ever you apply the script to an object it will then be applied to any other object which has the `SpawnFood` script as default values.

Comment: i know it and I should have revised them as prefabs .,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second image are **default** references. If you set them they are automatically applied after adding this script to an object.

**They are not required.** And only apply to a script added via the Editor (not by script!). What matters later on runtime are only the values on the GameObject.

Further you can only reference assets from the Assets folder here. They make sense e.g. if you have a button script that uses a certain Click sound, a texture and e.g. a prefab. For these three you now could already define default values so someone using your component doesn't have to assign everything everytime but already has the default references as a kind of fallback.

---

So in your case it would only make sense, if the borders are prefabs from the Assets that are spawned by this script. The `FoodPrefab` is even called like this and makes sense to have as a default reference so you don't have to drag it into each and every instance of `SpawnFood` you create.

And btw just by looking at your settings you should probably directly make your fields of type `RectTransform` so you can't accidentally reference another object there.

Comment: Actually,I don't know  as well  why I can't put the prefab in the  border column instead of the object itself  ? Is it prohibited according to the rules ?

Comment: Besides, the value of the second image still can't be synced ,which , However ,the script can function normally

Comment: @masod The values are not "synced" especially if you modify them after you already created an instance they do nothing. The only thing they do is getting applied to a new instance of your script in the editor. If your border prefab sits in the Assets you will be able to reference it. You can't reference scene objects as default references.

Comment: You means scene objects /= prefabs , we can only reference prefab  .Also , what's your meaning of default reference ? In unity , there's no default reference . is it? I mean , people they need to reference all the things on their own .the system (unity)won't help them

Comment: @masod Nope. As said your second image shows the **default references** (it even says this in the HelpBox ;) ) These references as also said are automatically assigned by the system (unity) if a user adds this script/component to a new GameObject via the Editor (if done via script on runtime then yes you have to assign the values "manually"). And yes SceneObjects /= prefabs! You can only use **assets** as default references in the script import settings. Within the scene the user has to do it all on his own.

Comment: Thx you so much . I now understand it!